# Best practice writing AngularJS controller in Typescript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I am really new to AngularJS and Web Development and more experienced in C# and C++.
Because of that I try to use Typescript.

I am working on a controller right now and got some strange behavior. 
When using the login-function like in the code below a have the problem, that the services sessionService and userDataService are not defined inside the then-statement. 
It is accessible before and after the then.

```
class UserController {
  scope: UserControllerScope;
  location: ng.ILocationService;
  sessionService: SessionService;
  userDataService: UserDataService;

  constructor($scope: UserControllerScope,
              $location: ng.ILocationService,
              userDataService: UserDataService,
              sessionService: SessionService){
    this.scope = $scope;
    this.location = $location;
    this.userDataService = userDataService;
    this.sessionService = sessionService;
  }

  loginUser(username: string, pw: string) {
    var foundUser;
    console.log(this.sessionService);
    console.log(this.userDataService);
    console.log("Got into LoginUser");

    this.userDataService.getUserAsync(username, pw).then(function(foundUserFromDb) {
      console.log(this.sessionService);
      console.log(this.userDataService);
    });

    console.log(this.sessionService);
    console.log(this.userDataService);
    this.location.path("views/projects.html")
  }
}
```

Is there a way the custom services needs to be injected so that they can be access everywhere in the class or do you have better ways to deal with the injection of services and controllers?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you creating the controller? Are you minifying your JavaScript? How are you registering your services? Also instead of saying `this.scope = $scope` you can just change the constructor parameter to `public $scope: UserControllerScope` but that's not what is causing your issue.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
The answer of Anthony Chu lend me to the problem. It was using "this" directly in then-context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in the context of `then()` isn't the controller. You have to capture `this` into another variable like `self`. TypeScript will do this for you if you use arrow functions...

```
loginUser = (username: string, pw: string) => {
    var foundUser;
    console.log(this.sessionService);
    console.log(this.userDataService);
    console.log("Got into LoginUser");

    this.userDataService.getUserAsync(username, pw).then(foundUserFromDb => {
        console.log(this.sessionService);
        console.log(this.userDataService);
    });

    console.log(this.sessionService);
    console.log(this.userDataService);
    this.location.path("views/projects.html")
}
```

The compiled JavaScript should look something like this...

```
var _this = this;
this.loginUser = function (username, pw) {
    var foundUser;
    console.log(_this.sessionService);
    console.log(_this.userDataService);
    console.log("Got into LoginUser");

    _this.userDataService.getUserAsync(username, pw).then(function (foundUserFromDb) {
        console.log(_this.sessionService);
        console.log(_this.userDataService);
    });

    console.log(_this.sessionService);
    console.log(_this.userDataService);
    _this.location.path("views/projects.html");
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I must have overseen that this changes in the then-context. Now it works perfectly.